# Time if statement not working

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I have a simple if statement which compares to dates, however its not running, I have tried debugging it but doesn't work.

```
dateFormat = "01/05/2099"
dateMissing = "25/11/2016"

if(dateFormat > dateMissing){
  dateFormat = dateMissing;
}
```

Comment: dates or strings?

Comment: try `dateFormat = new Date("01/05/2099")`

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: No, `Date` is not defined to understand that format.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah I was just hinting, hence why it was a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing **strings**. That compares their characters, one by one from left-to-right, until it finds a difference, and then uses that difference as the result. Since `"2"` is `>` `"0"`, that string is greater than the other.

You need to parse the dates and compare the result. **Do not** just use `new Date(dateFormat)` or similar, those strings are not in a format that is handled by JavaScript's `Date` object. Do the parsing yourself (directly, or via a library). E.g.

```js
var dateFormat = "01/05/2099";
var dateMissing = "25/11/2016";
var parts, dt1, dt2;
var parts = dateFormat.split("/");
var dt1 = new Date(+parts[2], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[0]);
parts = dateMissing.split("/");
var dt2 = new Date(+parts[2], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[0]);
if (dt1 > dt2) {
    dateFormat = dateMissing;
}
console.log("dateFormat:", dateFormat);
console.log("dt1", dt1.toString());
console.log("dt2", dt2.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can't simply compare the strings containing dates. First, convert them to an acceptable format (milliseconds).

```
var dateFormat = new Date("05/01/2099").getTime();
var dateMissing = new Date("11/25/2016").getTime();
```

Then you can do your date comparision.

Comment: "*Your can't simply compare the strings containing dates*. You can if they are formatted correctly, using *localeCompare*, e.g. `'2099-01-05'.localeCompare('2016-11-25')`. ;-)